# Convert azimuth to degrees

Tags: degrees, azimuth

What is a generic formula for converting azimuth(from -180 to 180) to degrees(from 0 to 360)?

```
double azimuth = (Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[0]));
           if(azimuth < 0){
               azimuth += 360;
           }
           azimuth -= 90;
           if(azimuth < 0){
               azimuth += 360;
           }
```

That's what I have tried but it doesn't seemed to work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is actually about basic mathematics. I believe it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/ (Mathematics) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several conventions for azimuths ("geological", "geohraphical"  - clockwise, anticlockwise). What´s wrong with 
`double azimuth = (Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[0])) + 180.0;` ? Seems to do what you request.